# Appending results of multiple table Queries

Tags: sql-server

I've been looking high and low for some answer to this, but haven't found any documentation on conducting this kind of operation in SQL.  Basically, I have a parameter list that is too large to run one query for, so my first thought is to break up this list of parameters and create a single sql script that takes subsets of the parameter list, runs a query for each list, and then appends all of the results into one table.

I.e, first query would return...

```
- id | DeviceName
- 00   201341
- 01   324232
- ...  ...
```

second one returns...

```
 - id | DeviceName 
 - 02   253242 
 - 03   234234 
 - ...  ...
```

And the objective is to have all these results appended / combined into one big table that has all the values in it.

Is it possible to do this in SQL all in the same script?  I've found articles like this one on MSDN, but I'm unsure if this really does what I'm trying to achieve.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ethytz2x.aspx

I also tried searching around stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to find anything that sounds quite like the same problem.

I'm not exactly an expert on SQL, so maybe I'm missing something with how the join and union works?  I've used those to join information from different columns into one table, but not so much to append rows.

Edit: 
To give a more concrete example of what I'm dealing with, this is basically the script I'm trying to modify to avoid having too many parameters...

```
   <sql-query name="GetMyDogsStatus">
  <query-param name="DogIds" type="Guid"/>
  <return-scalar column="status" type="Guid"/>
  <![CDATA[
  DECLARE @DogIds dbo.EntityIds
  INSERT INTO @DogIds (dogID)
  SELECT dogID from Dogs
  WHERE dogID in (:DogIds)
  DECLARE @tempId uniqueidentifier
  DECLARE @dogStatus varchar(255)
  DECLARE @InjuredDogIds dbo.EntityIds
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT dogId from @DogIds
  OPEN cur
  FETCH next from cur
  INTO @tempId
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
     SELECT @dogStatus = null
     SELECT TOP 1 @dogStatus = ev.[Delete Status]
     FROM EventsHistory ev
     WHERE dogId = @tempId
           AND ev.[Delete Status] IS NOT NULL
           AND ev.[Delete Status] != ''
           AND ev.[Delete Status] != 'Pending'
     ORDER BY [Time Deleted] DESC
     if(@dogStatus is not null and not (@dogStatus='healthy' or @dogStatus='incomplete health assessment'))
        insert into @InjuredDogIds (dogId) values (@tempId)
  FETCH next from cur
  INTO @tempId
  END
  CLOSE cur
  DEALLOCATE cur
  SELECT dogid as 'status' FROM @InjuredDogIds
  ]]>
```

There might be typos since I was swapping around table names in the example.

Comment: What do you mean the parameter list is too large? Are you saying that you are creating a parameterized query and you have exceeded the maximum amount of allowed parameters? If so, your query is being done completely wrong. You should never get anywhere near close to that threshold. If it is something else, you need to explain more clearly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Also, I assume this is sql server from the MSDN link but not really sure. Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: What not take the list of parameters you have create a temp table in the database; then use a bulk insert and then do your query using limits based on your temp table.  This way You don't have to pass in parameters to a specific query

Comment: If you could provide some sample data to work with (see [this from the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more) we can probably help you get your query working, without the need to split or apply complex logic.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to solve the issue of having 2100+ GUIDs being passed to a where clause.  Also, it's SQL server.

Comment: If the list of guids is simply a list of values you want returned you should look into table valued parameters. This is exactly the kind of thing they were designed to handle.

Comment: @SeanLange I'll go review table valued parameters as well.  I think that Davids answer below got me going in the right direction so if anything comes up I'll leave an update.

Comment: @destination-data I'll post example data if I have further issues.  As I stated in the answer below I think that FDavidov got me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please specify if it is MySQL or sql-server. Second, check the use of `union`. Its purpose is to concatenate the results of several queries into a single dataset (the condition is that the results of all queries have the same structure, which I understand is your case). For instance:

```
SELECT ID , DEVICENAME FROM <yourTable> WHERE <filtering condition 1>
UNION
SELECT ID , DEVICENAME FROM <yourTable> WHERE <filtering condition 2>
UNION
SELECT ID , DEVICENAME FROM <yourTable> WHERE <filtering condition 3>
...
```

Comment: It is best to avoid using answers for extended comments.  See [this on the meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette) for more.

Comment: As far as I'm concern, mine was not just a comment but a guidance to a solution. Also, I added an example to make it more substantial.

Comment: It's SQL Server in this case.  I'll try out using union again to see if this solves the issue.  I might be getting confused due to a lot of the other answers showing up on the stack overflow search for more complex issues.

Comment: Yes, try the `UNION` but make sure that your filtering conditions prevent overlaps (i.e. a record appearing in more than one **select** result).

Comment: @FDavidov No need for this, as `UNION` already eliminates duplicates. Only way to keep duplicates is by using `UNION ALL`. [Source info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: I think this got me going in the right direction.  I'll post any updates if I run into a more concrete problem.  Thanks FDavidov and everyone!